# Property auth of the cookie can't be read

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm setting a cookie and the cookie is successfully saved when i view from the browser, However when i try to read it's value from another file an error appears **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined"**, where auth is the name of the cookie.

```
const User=require('../models/user');

const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
let authTken = req.cookie.auth;
console.log(authTken);
return User.findbyTokenAndValidate(authTken)
.then((user)=>{
    if (user)
    return next();
    else return Promise.reject()
})
.catch((err)=>{

    console.log( err);
res.status('401');                                                                                                                                                    

})
```

**This is the  error i'm getting :**
TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined
    at authenticate (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/middleware/authenticate.js:4:31)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/Mohannad/Desktop/WORK/Book/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)

Comment: Check that you have cookie-parser configurea in the server https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser

Comment: yes, i already have the cookie-parser configured in my root file @vitomadio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [req.cookies](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.cookies) you want to use, not `req.cookie`

Comment: @mohannadrateb if you have more issues then you will need to either open a new question or provide more information, as it stands this is the fix for your original problem.

Comment: I tried this, what happens is a lot of stuff gets printed in the terminal without reaching the then or the catch block

Comment: @mohannadrateb as I said, sounds like these are other problems out with your original one of not being able to read the cookie.